# Shuffle given array

Tags: php, arrays, search, shuffle, tag-cloud

I have this tag cloud, which is currently set to show the most popular item first with the use of (line 205):

```
//              arsort($array_end);
```

which reverses the array. If i leave this out it shows the list alphabetically.

I would like to have the results shown randomly. I thought of php-shuffle, but i don't know how to go about it. Appreciate if someone could help me out here, Cheers!

See php below [(also uploaded php here as .txt)](http://www.lassooydesign.nl/custom/popular-searches-tag-cloud.txt):

```
//activate plugin WP function

//Checking search meter dependencies
global $wpdb, $table_prefix;
$sql = "SHOW TABLES LIKE '{$table_prefix}searchmeter_recent'";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
if (!$wpdb->num_rows )
{
    die( '<p>This plugin will not work unless <a href="http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-meter/" target="_blank">Search Meter plugin</a> is installed and activated.</p>' );
}


register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'initializeSearchTagCloud');

//activat plugin WP function
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'deactivateSearchTagCloud');

//set initial values when the plugin is activated
function initializeSearchTagCloud()
{
    $search_tag_cloud=new searchTagCloud();
    $search_tag_cloud->initializeSearchTagCloud();
}

//delete DB options when the plugin is activated
function deactivateSearchTagCloud() {
    delete_option("searchTagCloudOption");
}

class searchTagCloud
{
    public $widgetText;
    public $numberSearches;
    public $max_size;
    public $min_size;
    public $days_to_display;
    var $error;

    //constuctor function
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->min_size=12;
        $this->max_size=32;
        $this->widgetText = 'What people is searching?';
        $this->total_tags=10;
        $this->show_author_credit=0;
        $this->days_to_display=30;
        //the size of the tag cloud is missed
    }

    //initialize options
    //size of the smallest tag
    //maximum size of the biggest tag
    //Personalized text for the tag cloud
    //how many links to display
    function initializeSearchTagCloud()
    {
        global $wpdb, $table_prefix;
        $wpdb->query("ALTER TABLE `{$table_prefix}searchmeter_recent` ADD COLUMN visible INT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'");

        $initializeOptions = array(
        "min_size"      => $this->min_size,
        "max_size"     => $this->max_size,
        "total_tags"     => $this->total_tags,
        "widgetText" => $this->widgetText,
        "days_to_display" => $this->days_to_display,
        "show_author_credit" => $this->show_author_credit,
        );
        add_option("searchTagCloudOption", $initializeOptions, '', 'yes');  
        //select recent searched terms
    }   

    //get DB options for the Search Tag Cloud
    function getSearchTagCloudOptions()
    {
        $myOptions = get_option('searchTagCloudOption');
        $this->min_size=$myOptions['min_size'];
        $this->max_size=$myOptions['max_size'];
        $this->widgetText=$myOptions['widgetText'];
        $this->total_tags=$myOptions['total_tags']; 
        $this->days_to_display=$myOptions['days_to_display'];   
        $this->show_author_credit=$myOptions['show_author_credit'];
    }

    //set Search Tag Cloud class values
    function setSearchTagCloudValues($min_size,$max_size,$total_tags,$widgetText,$show_author_credit,$days_to_display)
    {
        $this->min_size=$min_size;
        $this->max_size=$max_size;
        $this->widgetText=$widgetText;
        $this->total_tags=$total_tags;  
        $this->show_author_credit=$show_author_credit;
        $this->days_to_display=$days_to_display;
    }

    //update Search Tag Cloud class values and DB options
    function updateSearchTagCloud($array_post)
    {       
        global $wpdb, $table_prefix;

        $this->setSearchTagCloudValues($array_post['min_size'],$array_post['max_size'],$array_post['total_tags'],$array_post['widgetText'],$array_post['show_author_credit'],$array_post['days_to_display']);

        //set the new options in the database
        update_option("searchTagCloudOption", $array_post, '', 'yes');

        //I set all to visible
        $wpdb->query("UPDATE `{$table_prefix}searchmeter_recent` SET visible=1");

        if(is_array($array_post['checkbox_visible']))
        {
            foreach($array_post['checkbox_visible'] as $index=>$value)
                $wpdb->query("UPDATE `{$table_prefix}searchmeter_recent` SET visible=0 WHERE terms = '{$value}'");  
        }
        return __("Options Saved Correctly");
    }

    //Function to select from search meter tables in the database the most common searches. 
    function select_searches_for_tagcloud() 
    {
        // List the most recent successful searches.
        global $wpdb, $table_prefix;
        $this->getSearchTagCloudOptions();
        $count = intval($this->total_tags);

        //first I need to know how many invisible tags we have

        //select terms, COUNT( * ) AS total FROM `wp_searchmeter_recent` WHERE datetime>='2010-07-05' GROUP BY `terms` LIMIT 0,15

        //$datebeginning = date()-dÌas
        $datebeginning  = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"),date("d")-$this->days_to_display, date("Y")));

        $tags = $wpdb->get_results(
        //select recent searched terms
            " SELECT terms, visible, COUNT( * ) AS total
                FROM `{$table_prefix}searchmeter_recent`
                WHERE datetime>='{$datebeginning}' AND
                hits>0 AND
                visible=1
                GROUP BY `terms`
                LIMIT {$count}");

        return $tags;   
    }

    function selectPopularSearchesforAdmin()
    {
        // List the most recent successful searches.
        global $wpdb, $table_prefix;
        $this->getSearchTagCloudOptions();
        $count = intval($this->total_tags);

        //first I need to know how many invisible tags we have

        //select terms, COUNT( * ) AS total FROM `wp_searchmeter_recent` WHERE datetime>='2010-07-05' GROUP BY `terms` LIMIT 0,15

        //$datebeginning = date()-dÌas
        $datebeginning  = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"),date("d")-$this->days_to_display, date("Y")));

        $invisible_tags = $wpdb->get_results(
            " SELECT terms, COUNT( * ) AS total
                FROM `{$table_prefix}searchmeter_recent`
                WHERE visible=1 AND
                `datetime`>='{$datebeginning}' AND
                hits>0
                GROUP BY `terms`
                LIMIT {$count}");

        // I have to show the tags plus the invisible ones
        $count = $count + count($invisible_tags);

        $tags = $wpdb->get_results(
        //select recent searched terms
            " SELECT terms, visible, COUNT( * ) AS total
                FROM `{$table_prefix}searchmeter_recent`
                WHERE datetime>='{$datebeginning}' AND
                hits>0
                GROUP BY `terms`
                LIMIT {$count}");

        return $tags;       
    }   

    //function that creates the tag cloud and prints it.
    function popular_searches_tag_cloud($args)
    {
            $results=$this->select_searches_for_tagcloud();

            if(count($results)>0)
            {
                foreach($results as $index)
                {
                    $array_end[$index->terms]=$index->total;
                }

//              arsort($array_end);


                // largest and smallest array values
                $max_qty = max(array_values($array_end));
                $min_qty = min(array_values($array_end));

                // find the range of values
                $spread = $max_qty - $min_qty;
                if ($spread == 0) { // we don't want to divide by zero
                        $spread = 1;
                }

                // set the font-size increment
                $step = ($this->max_size - $this->min_size) / ($spread);

                //set the counter for the loop at 0
                $counter=0;

                // loop through the tag array
                if(count($array_end)>0)
                {
                    $html='<div class="search-tag-cloud">';
                    $html.='<h2>'.$this->widgetText.'</h2>';
                    foreach ($array_end as $key => $value) 
                    {
                        if($counter<=$this->total_tags)
                        {
                            $counter++;
                            // calculate font-size
                            // find the $value in excess of $min_qty
                            // multiply by the font-size increment ($size)
                            // and add the $min_size set above
                            $size = round($this->min_size + (($value - $min_qty) * $step));

                            $html.= '<a href="?s=' . $key . '" style="font-size: ' . $size . 'px" 
                            title="' . $key . '">' . $key . '</a> ';
                        }
                        else
                            break;      
                    }

                    if($this->show_author_credit==1)
                        $html.='<div id="search-tag-cloud"><p style="text-align:right"><small>WP plugin by <a href="http://www.josellinares.com/tag/marketing-online/" title="Marketing Online" target="_blank">Marketing Online</a></small></p></div>';

                    $html.='</div>';
                    echo $html;
                }
            }
    }
}
/*end class--------------------------------*/


//setting the admin page
//create admin->settings page
//create Settings Section to configure plugin values
if (is_admin() ){ // admin actions
    add_action('set_twitter_keyword_values','set_twitter_keyword');
    add_action('admin_menu','admin_setSearchTagCloud');
    add_action('admin_init','searchTagCloudSettings' );
} else {
  // non-admin enqueues, actions, and filters
}

//adding the page in the admin section
function admin_setSearchTagCloud() {
    add_options_page('Popular Searches Tag Cloud Options', 'Popular Searches Tag Cloud', 8,__FILE__, 'searchTagCloudOptions');
}

//register form fields
function searchTagCloudSettings() { // whitelist options
    register_setting('search-tag-cloud-options', 'widgetText', 'wp_filter_nohtml_kses');
    register_setting('search-tag-cloud-options', 'max_size', 'checkValueisInt');
    register_setting('search-tag-cloud-options', 'min_size', 'checkValueisInt');
    register_setting('search-tag-cloud-options', 'total_tags', 'checkValueisInt');
    register_setting('search-tag-cloud-options', 'checkbox_visible');
    register_setting('search-tag-cloud-options', 'show_author_credit', 'checkValueisInt');
    register_setting('search-tag-cloud-options', 'days_to_display', 'checkValueisInt');
}

function searchTagCloudOptions() 
{   
    $html= '<div class="wrap">';
    $html= '<form method="post">';
    settings_fields('search-tag-cloud-options');
    $html.= '<h2>'. __("Popular Searches Tag Cloud Options: Manage Options").'</h2>';
    if($_POST['type-submit']=='Y')
    {
        $message=updateSearchTagCloudForm($_POST);
        if($message!='')
            $html.= '<div class="error"><p><strong>'.$message.'</strong></p></div>';
        else
            $html.= '<div class="updated"><p><strong>'.__("Options Saved").'</strong></p></div>';
        $myOptions=get_option('searchTagCloudOption');
    }
    else
        $myOptions=get_option('searchTagCloudOption');

    $html.= '<label for="newpost-edited-text">'.__('Set the header for the Popular Searches Tag Cloud to be visible: ').'</label>';
    $html.= '<input type="text" name="widgetText" size="40" maxlength="150" value="'.$myOptions['widgetText'].'" /><br /><br />';
    $html.= '<label for="newpost-edited-text">'.__('Size of the biggest tag: ').'</label>';
    $html.= '<input type="text" name="max_size" size="10" maxlength="3" value="'.$myOptions['max_size'].'" /><br /><br />';
    $html.= '<label for="newpost-edited-text">'.__('Size of the smallest tag: ').'</label>';
    $html.= '<input type="text" name="min_size" size="10" maxlength="3" value="'.$myOptions['min_size'].'" /><br /><br />';
    $html.= '<label for="newpost-edited-text">'.__('Number of searches to display: ').'</label>';
    $html.= '<input type="text" name="total_tags" size="10" maxlength="3" value="'.$myOptions['total_tags'].'" /><br /><br />';
    $html.= '<label for="newpost-edited-text">'.__('You want to show searches from the last : ').'</label>';
    $html.= '<input type="text" name="days_to_display" size="10" maxlength="3" value="'.$myOptions['days_to_display'].'" /> days<br /><br />';
    $html.=getMostPopularSearchesAdmin($results, 15, false);
    $html.= '<br /><br /><label for="newpost-edited-text">'.__('Display developer credits in the Widget: ').'</label>';
    $html.= '<input type="checkbox" name="show_author_credit" value="1" ';

    if ($myOptions['show_author_credit']==1) 
            $html.='checked';

    $html.='/><br /><br />';    
    $html.= '<input type="hidden" name="type-submit" value="Y">';
    $html.= '<br><input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="'.__('Save Options').'" />';

    //here I need the list of all searches, order by total
    $html.= '</form>';
    $html.= '</div>';

    echo $html;
}

//function to show common searches to edit in the admin page. Completes the admin form.
function getMostPopularSearchesAdmin(){

    $searchcloud=new searchTagCloud();
    $results=$searchcloud->selectPopularSearchesforAdmin();

    if (count($results)) {
        $html='<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2">';
        $html.='<tbody>';
        $html.='<tr class="alternate"><th class="left">Term</th><th>Set not Visible</th>';
        if ($do_include_successes) {
            $html.='<th>Results</th>';
        }
        $html.='</tr>';
        $class= '';
        $counter=0;
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $html.='<tr class="'.$class.'">';
            $html.='<td><a href="'.get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/wp-admin/edit.php?s='.urlencode($result->terms).'&submit=Search">'.htmlspecialchars($result->terms).'</a></td>';
            $html.='<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_visible['.$counter.']" value="'.$result->terms.'" ';

            if ($result->visible==0) 
                $html.='checked';
            $html.='/>';            
            $html.='</td>';
            $html.='</tr>';

            $class = ($class == '' ? 'alternate' : '');

            $counter++;
        }

        $html.='</tbody>';
        $html.='</table>';


    } else {
        $html.='<p>No searches recorded for this period.</p>';
    }
    return $html;
}

//This functions checks the data send by the form and calls the update the option.
function updateSearchTagCloudForm($array)
{
    $message='';
    $search_tag_cloud=new searchTagCloud();

    //check values before inserting into DB
    $message=checkNumbers($array['max_size']);
    $message.=checkNumbers($array['min_size']);
    $message.=checkNumbers($array['total_tags']);
    $message.=checkSearchCloudWidgetText($array['widgetText']);
    $message.=checkNumbers($array['days_to_display']);

    if($array['show_author_credit'])
        $message.=checkNumbers($array['show_author_credit']);

    if($message!='')
        return $message;    

    if($message=='')    
    {   
        $search_tag_cloud->updateSearchTagCloud($array);
    }
}

//checking function for the form fields functions in the admin page
function checkNumbers($number)
{   
    if(!intval( $number ))
        return __("The field maximum size and minimum size have to be numeric<br />");
    elseif($number>100)
        return __("Maximum size and minimum size have to be smaller than 100<br />");
    else
        return "";
}

//checking function for the form fields functions in the admin page
function checkSearchCloudWidgetText($widgetText)
{
    if(strlen($widgetText)>150)
    {
        return __("You are not allowed to include more than 150 characters in the Widget Text<br />");
    }   
    return "";
}

//Widgetizing the plugin functions
function setSearchTagCloudPlugin()
{
  register_sidebar_widget(__('Popular Searches Tag Cloud'), 'callSearchTagCloud'); 
  register_widget_control(__('Popular Searches Tag Cloud'), 'callSearchTagCloud', 200, 200 );
}

add_action("plugins_loaded", "setSearchTagCloudPlugin");

//function to initailize the class. Called from sidebar.php, it checks dependencies from the search meter plugin.
function callSearchTagCloud()
{
    global $wpdb, $table_prefix;

    $sql = "SHOW TABLES LIKE '{$table_prefix}searchmeter_recent'";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
    if ( ! $wpdb->num_rows )
    {
        die( '<p>This plugin will not work unless <a href="http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-meter/" target="_blank">Search Meter plugin</a> is installed and activated. -- widget</p>' );
    }
    else
    {
        $search_tag_cloud=new searchTagCloud();
        $search_tag_cloud->initializeSearchTagCloud();
    }
    $searchcloud=new searchTagCloud();
    $searchcloud->popular_searches_tag_cloud($tags,$args);  
}

    function setSearchTagCloudControl()
    {
      echo '<p><label for="myHelloWorld-WidgetTitle">To configure options go to     "Settings > Popular Searches Tag Cloud" in this admin panel</label></p>';
     }
```

Comment: Uhm... `shuffle($array_end)`? This is way too much code to be of any use in clarifying your problem with this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) function:

> This function shuffles (randomizes the order of the elements in) an array.

A little below

```
//              arsort($array_end);`
```

You got this code:

```
               foreach ($array_end as $key => $value) 
               {
```

Replace it with this:

```
               $array_end_keys = array_keys($array_end);
               shuffle($array_end_keys);
               foreach ($array_end_keys as $key) 
               {
                   $value = $array_end[$key];
```

Comment: Hi, i tried the shuffle function. 
In this case the shuffle function shuffles the fontsizes instead of the order. Also, it doesn't show the search keywords anymore, but it shows numbers (1,2,3,4,5,..)

Comment: Shuffle indeed does not keep the keys. I've changed my post to shuffle the keys and loop trough them to get the random order